# Google Maps JavaScript StreetView bug

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, prototypejs

The newest release version of the Google Maps JavaScript (3.32.13) is conflicting with Prototype.js version 1.7.3.

When I have Prototype included on the page, the Street View of Google Maps will not handle mouse drags to "look around"

Is this a known issue? Any workarounds?

Comment: I also have the situation you are talking about - I'm attempting to figure out why the events are not firing.

Comment: Probably Prototype.js polyfills some objects or functions that were included in ES6 standard. I've seen some issues with prototype and Google maps api due to Function#bind.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So the problem is that PrototypeJS is overwriting `Array.from` as an alias to `$A()` which creates an extended Array object.

IF (big IF) you are not using `Array.from` to create a shallow copy of an array and expecting the Prototype extended methods, you can remove/comment out the line in prototype.js that is only

```
Array.from = $A;
```

In my copy of 1.7.3 it is line 1114

Comment: Thank you! I was not relying on prototype.js's Array.from. This worked!

Answer (score 8):

I also struggled with the conflict between Prototype.js and Google API. Removing Prototype.js was not an option as it is deeply engrained in the project. I decided to replace

```
Array.from = $A;
```

by

```
Array.from = Array.from || $A;
```

in the prototype.js file. It keeps the support for older browsers which do not have Array.from implemented natively. This does not solve the conflict between Prototype.js and Google API on older browsers though!

> This site overrides Array.from() with an implementation that doesn't support iterables, which could cause Google Maps JavaScript API v3 to not work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I also have the same issue. So, I reopened a relevant GM API tkt: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72690631

I tried to rename the function collect into prototype.js but it didn't work.

Comment: Thank you for drawing attention to this!