# Conflict with prototype.js when using element.js (googleTranslateElement) to translating whole web

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, google-translate

Example:

1. Code that works and displays google translate toolbar:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script>
      function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({
          pageLanguage: 'pl'
        }, 'google_translate_element');
      }
    </script>
    <script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Code that does not display google translate toolbar:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.3.0/prototype.js"></script>
    <script>
      function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({
          pageLanguage: 'pl'
        }, 'google_translate_element');
      }
    </script>
    <script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The difference: adding prototype.js.

Error in the console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnYBJ.png)

What should I do for the google translate element to work with the prototype.js?
I would like to add that about 3 months ago everything was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that you are hit with the same conflict that happens on Google Maps Javascript API.

Try my answer on this question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50594159/341491